# swift problem with class with multiple objects

Tags: swift, class

Hi this is my first swift code. I'm trying to define a class which is going to be used to fill a new objet.

My first class is Evento it works fine.

```
import Foundation

class Evento {
    let indice: Int?
    let nombre: String
    let estado: Estado
    let precio: Double?
    let imagenes: [String]?
    let descipcion: String
    let urlWeb: String?
    let urlRRSS: [String]?
    let empresa: String?
    let email: String
    let telefono: String
    let direccion: String
    let fecha: String
    let lat, lon: Double?
    let tags: [String]
    
    init(nombre: String,  estado: Estado, descipcion: String, precio: Double? ,email: String, telefono: String, direccion: String, fecha: String, tags: [String])
    {
        self.indice = nil
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.estado = Estado.nopublicado
        self.precio = precio
        self.imagenes = []
        self.descipcion = descipcion
        self.urlWeb = nil
        self.urlRRSS = nil
        self.empresa = nil
        self.email = email
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.direccion = direccion
        self.fecha = fecha
        self.lat = nil
        self.lon = nil
        self.tags = tags
    }
      
    init(indice: Int?, nombre: String,  estado: Estado, precio: Double?, imagenes: [String]?, descipcion: String, urlWeb: String?, urRRSS: [String]?, empresa: String, email: String, telefono: String, direccion: String, fecha: String, lat: Double?, lon: Double?, tags: [String])
    {
        self.indice = indice
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.estado = Estado.nopublicado
        self.precio = precio
        self.imagenes = []
        self.descipcion = descipcion
        self.urlWeb = ""
        self.urlRRSS = []
        self.empresa = empresa
        self.email = email
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.direccion = direccion
        self.fecha = fecha
        self.lat = 0.0
        self.lon = 0.0
        self.tags = tags
    }
    
    enum Estado{
        case nopublicado, activo, retrasado, candelado,terminado
    }
    
    func publicarEventoInfoBasica(nombre: String, descripcion: String, fecha: String){
        print("Información sobre el evento: \(nombre) que se celebrará el \(fecha))")
        }
    

    func precioEventoDescuento(descuento: Double, precio: Double)-> Double{
        var precioReal = 0.0
        precioReal = descuento * precio
        return precioReal
    }         
}
```

Later I have a second class Eventos which I use to fill with Evento but I dont know how to do it

```
import Foundation

class Eventos {
    var eventos:[Evento] = []
    
}
```

And this is my main program

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        
        let evento1 = Evento(nombre: "Fiesta bienvenida UCAM", estado: .activo,  descipcion: "Fiesde inicio del curso para toda la comunidad eduacativa de la UCAM", precio:24.50, email: "secretaria@ucam.es", telefono: "69685474", direccion: "Univesidad San Antonio", fecha: "11/10/2022", tags: ["UCAM","FIESTA","BIENVENIDA"])
        
        let evento2 = Evento(nombre: "Fiesta navidad", estado: .nopublicado,  descipcion: "Fiesde del nacimiento de Nuestro Señor Jesús", precio:0.0, email: "iglesiasananton@ucam.es", telefono: "965452123", direccion: "Iglesia San Antón", fecha: "25/12/2022", tags: ["NAVIDAD","FIESTA"])
        
        **//here is my problem I dont know how to fill the list of eventos
        var eventosPendientes = Eventos()
        eventosPendientes = [evento1 , evento2]**
                        
        //Ejemplo de uso de un metodo creado en la clase
        let precioReal = evento1.precioEventoDescuento(descuento: 0.5,  precio: evento1.precio ?? 0.0)
          
        print("Recuerda que el próximo \(evento1.fecha) se celebra el evento de \(evento1.nombre) al que todos los alumnos estan invitados")
        
        print("El precio es gratuito para los estudiantes pero si traes a algun acompañante deberás pagar \(evento1.precio)€ por acompañante")
        
        print ("Al primer acompañante se le aplicará un descuento del 50% por lo que tendra que pagar:\(precioReal) ")
    
    }
}
```

Comment: `eventosPendientes` should probably be a property in your ViewController class rather than a local variable in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I guess you want to do something like `eventosPendientes.eventos = [evento1, evento2]`

Comment: Sorry I can't understand. Could you give a code example? Thx!

Comment: I just did, sorry but I can't give you a better example than in my previous comment since it is not clear to me what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: OK gret I got it. Thanks Joakim!!

Comment: And if I want to add a method in my class Eventos to add new evento how should I procee?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking?  You already fill the array by `=[evento1 , evento2]`.  Another option would to use `.append( )` to add entries to the array.  However unless, as above,  you change the variable in viewDidLoad to a property on your class, any content will be lost.